# Going through an array of obejct and extract a particular value

Tags: json, bash, sh, jq

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "12sd31sd",
            "name": "test1",
            "createdDate": 1554894979,
        },
        {
            "id": "sz978z7",
            "name": "test2",
            "createdDate": 1569595456,
        },
        {
            "id": "sd213sd121",
            "name": "test1",
            "createdDate": 1569592293,
        },
        {
            "id": "c4556c456c",
            "name": "test1",
            "createdDate": 1569592293,
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to loop through each object in this array, and pick out the id of each value name "test1"

at the moment i have an eror with

Don't know how to read the variable inside jq ..

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please post valid JSON.

Comment: it is a valid JSON

Comment: Try `jq '' file` and remove four commas.

Comment: You were already **very close** to the solution with your again removed attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which assumes corrected json in `test.json`

```
$ jq -M    '.items[] | select(.name == "test1") | .id' test.json
"12sd31sd"
"sd213sd121"
"c4556c456c"
```

You can use `-r` to exclude the quotes e.g.

```
$ jq -M -r '.items[] | select(.name == "test1") | .id' test.json
12sd31sd
sd213sd121
c4556c456c
```